# One-column abstract in KOMA-script

Tags: koma-script, two-column, abstract

I would like to make the abstract in KOMA Article appear on both columns, when writing a two column article. I would like to use internal koma options, instead of loading external packages. 
The following code sample works for me, but it is only to demonstrate what I want, not what I really want (which is not to use external packages like the abstract package)

```
\documentclass[twoside=false,
           twocolumn=true,
           a4paper,
           10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{abstract}


%opening
\title{Some Magnificant Article}
\author{Dr Brainy}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
\maketitle
\begin{onecolabstract}
Here is which one-column abstract resides
trying lipsum does not work here 
\end{onecolabstract}
]

\tableofcontents

\section{introduction}
\lipsum

\section{method}
\subsection{mptre}
\subsubsection{aasdasd}
\section{results}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `abstract` package documentation shows the standard way of doing this without using the package:

```
\makeatletter
\twocolumn[
   \begin{@twocolumnfalse} 
     \maketitle 
     \begin{abstract}
     This is a two column abstract. It will stretch over two columns.   
     \end{abstract}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
\makeatother
```

It's not clear you gain much from not using the package, though.

Answer (score 2):

Not for KOMA article class, but for `scrbook` and `scrreprt` there is the `\setpartpreamble` command. In my version of the docs (2012-07-22), p.95:

> Parts and chapters in KOMA-Script can be started with a preamble.
>   This is particularly useful when you are using a two column layout
>   with the class option `twocolumn`, since the heading together with the
>   *preamble* is always set in a one column layout. The *preamble* can
>   comprise more than one paragraph. The command to output the *preamble*
>   has to be placed before the respective `\part`, `\addpart`, `\chapter`, or
>   `\addchap` command.

And they provide this example:

```
\setpartpreamble{%
  \begin{abstract}
    This is a filler text. It serves merely to demonstrate the
    capabilities of {\KOMAScript}. If you read this text, you will
    get no information.
  \end{abstract}
}
\part{Department for Word Processing}
```